# Service should send data as an object

Tags: angular, service

I have a service that is used to send values from **SendComponent** to **ReceiveComponent**.

**SendComponent**

```
export class SendComponent implements OnInit {

  message1: string;
  message2: string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.data.currentMessage1.subscribe(message => this.message1 = message);
   this.data.currentMessage2.subscribe(message => this.message2 = message);    
  }

  newMessageCreator() {
    this.data.changeMessage1("New value for message 1");        
    this.data.changeMessage2("New value for message 2");    
  }

}
```

**ReceiveComponent**

```
export class ReceiveComponent implements OnInit {
  message1: string;
  message2: string;
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage1.subscribe(message => this.message1 = message);
    this.data.currentMessage2.subscribe(message => this.message2 = message);    
  }    
}
```

**DataService**

```
export class DataService {

      private messageSource1 = new BehaviorSubject('default message 1');
      private messageSource2 = new BehaviorSubject('default message 2');        

      public currentMessage1 = this.messageSource1.asObservable();
      public currentMessage2 = this.messageSource2.asObservable();      

      constructor() { }

      changeMessage1(message: string) {
        this.messageSource1.next(message)
      }

      changeMessage2(message: string) {
        this.messageSource2.next(message)
      }        
    }
```

This code is working. But I prefer that the service sends all messages from **SendComponent** to **ReceiveComponent** as an object ( `{message1: ..., message2: ...}` ) , rather than stand alone values. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understand but maybe something like that :

**SEND**

```
export class SendComponent implements OnInit {
    messages: {message1:string,message2:string};

    constructor(private data: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.data.currentMessages.subscribe(messages => this.messages = 
        {...this.messages,...message});
    }

     newMessageCreator() {
         this.data.changeMessages({message1:"New value for message 1"});         
         this.data.changeMessages({message2:"New value for message 2"});         
         //or
         this.data.changeMessages({message1:"New value for message 1", message2:"New 
          value for message 2"});         
     }
 }
```

**RECEIVE**

```
export class ReceiveComponent implements OnInit {
   messages: {message1:string,message2:string};
   constructor(private data: DataService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.data.currentMessages.subscribe(message => this.messages = 
       {...this.messages,...messages});
   }    
}
```

**DATE service**

```
 export class DataService {

     private messagesSource = new BehaviorSubject({message1:'default message 
                                                  1',message2:'default 2'});

     public currentMessages = this.messagesSource.asObservable();

     constructor() { }

     changeMessages(message: {message1:string,message2:string}) {
         this.messagesSource.next(message)
     }
}
```

It's not the best but it works I think :)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks!